# CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Error launching application on iPhone 13

Tags: cocoapods, launching

1.i received this error after updating android studio when i try to run the app but if i write flutter run on terminal the app run normally how to solve this issue
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

this is my flutter doctor massage 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-CU)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!

local gems


*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (6.1.4.1, 5.2.6, 4.2.11.3)
addressable (2.8.0)
algoliasearch (1.27.5)
atomos (0.1.3)
benchmark (default: 0.1.0)
bigdecimal (default: 2.0.0)
bundler (default: 2.1.4)
CFPropertyList (3.0.5)
cgi (default: 0.1.0)
claide (1.0.3)
cocoapods (1.11.2)
cocoapods-core (1.11.2, 1.10.0, 1.7.5)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (1.5.1)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-stats (1.1.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
colored2 (3.1.2)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
csv (default: 3.1.2)
date (default: 3.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.1.0)
delegate (default: 0.1.0)
did_you_mean (default: 1.4.0)
escape (0.0.4)
etc (default: 1.1.0)
ethon (0.15.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
ffi (1.15.5, 1.15.4)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.4.1)
forwardable (default: 1.3.1)
fourflusher (2.3.1)
fuzzy_match (2.0.4)
getoptlong (default: 0.1.0)
gh_inspector (1.1.3)
httpclient (2.8.3)
i18n (1.8.11, 0.9.5)
io-console (default: 0.5.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.2.3)
json (default: 2.3.0)
logger (default: 1.4.2)
matrix (default: 0.2.0)
minitest (5.13.0)
molinillo (0.8.0, 0.6.6)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
nanaimo (0.3.0)
nap (1.1.0)
net-pop (default: 0.1.0)
net-smtp (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
netrc (0.11.0)
observer (default: 0.1.0)
open3 (default: 0.1.0)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.2.0)
power_assert (1.1.7)
prime (default: 0.1.1)
pstore (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
public_suffix (4.0.6)
racc (default: 1.4.16)
rake (13.0.1)
rdoc (default: 6.2.1)
readline (default: 0.0.2)
readline-ext (default: 0.1.0)
reline (default: 0.1.3)
rexml (3.2.5, default: 3.2.3)
rss (default: 0.2.8)
ruby-macho (2.5.1, 1.4.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
setup (5.2.0)
singleton (default: 0.1.0)
stringio (default: 0.1.0)
strscan (default: 1.0.3)
test-unit (3.3.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
timeout (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
typhoeus (1.4.0)
tzinfo (2.0.4, 1.2.9)
uri (default: 0.10.0)
webrick (default: 1.6.0)
xcodeproj (1.21.0)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
yaml (default: 0.1.0)
zeitwerk (2.5.1)
zlib (default: 1.1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking "Check for updates..." and installing the updates that are available fixed this for me.

Comment: i tried it but didnot solve my error